# When is it correct to use $\Gamma(n)$ instead of $n!$ when $n$ is a positive integer?

Tags: notation, factorial

I have seen the notation $\Gamma(n)$ employed in many articles in which $n$ is defined as a nonzero positive integer, instead of $n!$. What is the advantage of using $\Gamma$ in such a context, given that it is the continuous analogue of the factorial?

---

**EDIT**

I am aware that $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$. My question relates more to the "concept" of using $\Gamma$ instead of the factorial function.

Comment: @Arthur Of course, sorry. I always mess that up when asking a question on MSE... I will edit it

Comment: The only advantage I can see when $n$ is given as a positive integer is that $\Gamma$ makes it easier to generalize a formula to nonintegers. Otherwise, I have mostly seen $\Gamma$ be used for arguments that are a multiple of $\frac12$, e.g. the volume of a $n$-sphere.